# Translate bar scroll fix

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a [website](http://ryansthemes.tumblr.com/), and I get a fair amount of traffic from portugal and many other places that speak languages other than English, so I wanted to put a translate option, which I have now done.

My issue is that with googles translate option, it creates a top banner asking if you meant that language, and clicking out of it (at least for me), un-translates the page. This is annoying, especially because, as you can see, the banner covers my main navigation banner, so you cannot see what links there are.

With position absolute, the navigation banner, along with the rest of the body, will drop down to fit in the google banner, but then the navigation banner does not stay at the top like I want it to.

**question: how can I make it so that it stays at the top during scrolling, but moves down when necessary so that the links can be viewed?**

note: creative solutions are fine, but I feel like there should be a simple fix that I am missing.

Just in case people want to see the css for the navigation banner, here:

```
#topbar{
    overflow:hidden;
    z-index:999;
    padding-left:20px;
    padding-right:20px;
    padding-top:5px;
    position:fixed;
    text-align:center;
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    background-image:url('http://www.wallgc.com/images/2012/11/black-minimalistic-dark-pattern-wall-textures-silver-HD-Wallpapers.jpg');
    background-color:#232323;
    margin-left:-20px;
    box-shadow: 0px 10px 10px -5px rgba(0,0,0,.6),inset 0px -1px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}
```

Comment: Please define "`when necessary`".

Comment: I'd recommend a plugin - this one is perfect http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/

Comment: @Teemu: I do...when the google web language changes, a pop up will come up and cover the navigation bar...go to the site I linked and change the language if you are confused.

Comment: @RyanSaxe Your page looks fine in Firefox, the Google banner appears above the whole page, it's not covering anything. A specific browser causing troubles?

Comment: guess firefox and chrome read `position:fixed` differently!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid I cannot access your page due to my work proxy settings, but perhaps your issue would be solved with this link?

http://joshua.doodnauth.com/blog/2011/03/google-web-translator-frame-bar/

Comment: Yes, that does solve my issue!! So if you could then answer this question...position fixed will set it apart from anything, including the body...is there a way to make it so that whenever something happens to the body, the equivalent happens to a specified id?

Comment: @RyanSaxe Potentially Yes, at least in theory. Can you clarify what you mean when you say 'something happens to the body' - what sort of thing? Thanks.